# How to update a column for multiple records dependant on other column values with sqlite python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I am writing some code to replace a hand written register for a disco event, the code uses a sqlite database to store the data. The table in the sqlite file has 4 columns: Name, Reply, Time_in and Time_out. By default Timein/out are empty they have nothing in them. The Name and Reply are imported via a csv file. At the end of the event if people haven't 'signed out' then the operator of the code presses a button (using tkinter) to update the remaining records. The data in the sqlite file looks like this:

`Name     Reply Time_in Time_out
JoeBlogs   Y`

I want the code to update all the records which have the Reply 'Y' and a time_in value but not a time_out value. I have tried to write this with python 2.7

```
c.execute("UPDATE Table1 SET Time_out = TIME('now') WHERE Time_in IS NOT NULL AND Time_out ISNUll AND Reply = 'Y'")                 
conn.commit()
```

Test data:

`Name    Reply   Time_in   Time_out
JoeBloggs Y     20:40:44
JohnSmith N
JohnBlogg Y
JoeSmith  Y     20:33:11  22:14:22`

After the update statement, there is no change to any of the records, so I also tried:

```
c.execute("UPDATE Table1 SET Time_out = TIME('now') WHERE Time_in IS NOT NULL AND Time_out ='' AND Reply = 'Y'")
```

conn.commit()

But this just overwrites previous Time_out values even if there was a value, it does this only for Reply Y which is a step forward. i.e.

`Name    Reply   Time_in   Time_out
JoeBloggs Y     20:40:44  22:44:22
JohnSmith N
JohnBlogg Y               22:44:22
JoeSmith  Y     20:33:11  22:44:22`

I was hoping for this result after the update statement:

`Name    Reply   Time_in   Time_out
JoeBloggs Y     20:40:44  22:44:22
JohnSmith N
JohnBlogg Y
JoeSmith  Y     20:33:11  22:14:22`

Can anyone point me towards the correct syntax for this problem?

Comment: Found an answer. I used '    WHERE Time_in<>'' and Time_out=''    '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:
`c.execute("UPDATE Table1 SET Time_out = TIME('now') WHERE Time_in<>'' and Time_out=''")

    conn.commit()`